# Syncfusion ribbons Tab - Alignment button to right

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I build application with `ribbonForm` by `Syncfusion` winform.
I want that in one of the ribbon tab it will be a button that alignment to right (all the other buttons alignment to the left).

I made paint to Demonstrate what I mean in the attached image[image].

How can I do that?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The tab area  of the `RibbonControlAdv` is a toolstriptabitem. By default its child is `ToolStripEx` but we can add other controls like button, by add it in toolstrippanel’s controls. To meet your requirement the button has been added to the right side of the Ribbon Tabs.

```
button = getButton();
this.toolStripTabItem1.Panel.Controls.Add(button);
this.toolStripTabItem1.Panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(button, this.toolStripTabItem1.Panel.Controls.Count - 1);
button.BringToFront();
```

You can also download a sample [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/94034/WindowsFormsApplication661-1932340175.zip).

Comment: Thanks. Its working good.
Its alittle work around, but its nice.
Thank you very much!